# Amazon DynamoDB query to get records based on user_id not on hash - key

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb

I Have One Query , i am using Amazon DynamoDB, and i want data from table where user_id === "1" , for that i have to scan whole table and then apply filter fnction on it , is there any way i get only that records from user === "1" , that will save my time complexity as i no longer need to loop over whole data.

Here Is What i Am using :

let data = await db.scan(params).promise();

```
  for (var i = 0; data.Items.length > i; i++) {
    if (e.id == data.Items[i].parts.createdBy) {
      arr.push(data.Items[i].parts);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create GSI with the user-id as the primary key.

Comment: Thanks , how we can query data from it using AWS sdk in js